# Updating images through Chipmunk (and any beginners guides)

Tags: chipmunk

so I am having some problems with chipmunk,
please realize that I am new and am just learning many of the ideas around chipmunk and if you have any good books, sources, or websites that I could use to learn chipmunk that would be great (please only current guides, I have walked through many old guides with outdated commands and have been quite frusterated).

but on to my main question, I am using Chipmunk and have used the "chipmunk tutorial" code that I found on an online web source. I am trying to attach an image (UIImageView *ball;) to the `ballBody->data` section, and trying to update the image but can not seem to figure it out, the code works but the image only moves to the ballBodys initial position.

Here is a sample of the code I'm using, let me know if I should supply any more information!

This is a timer that I call to update the chipmunk frames, When I call the "cpSpaceHashEach(space->activeShapes, &updateShape, nil);" section of the code I get the error that there is no object in called "active shapes in the struct cpspace, and thecpSpaceHash has an implicit declaration

```
// Called at each "frame" of the simulation
- (void)tick:(NSTimer *)timer {
    // Tell Chipmuck to take another "step" in the simulation
    cpSpaceStep(space, 1.0f/60.0f);

    // Call our function for each shape
    cpSpaceHashEach(space->activeShapes, &updateShape, nil);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking at a tutorial for 5.x and using Chipmunk 6.x.

"cpSpace.activeShapes" was documented as a private member in 5.x and is now gone. cpSpaceHashEach() was undocumented. It wasn't recommended to iterate the shapes using the snippet you gave because it caused a lot of undefined behavior, but everybody did it anyway.

In 6.x you should do this as it doesn't use any private, undocumented or undefined functionality:

```
cpSpaceEachShape(space, updateShape, NULL);
```

That said, I still wouldn't recommend iterating the shapes that way. You should keep a list of them yourself so you don't end up needing to skip static shapes and such.

You should take a look at the Simple Objective-Chipmunk Tutorial or the Snap example project on the Chipmunk downloads page: http://chipmunk-physics.net/downloads.php